# Php Logout issue in User panel and Admin panel

Tags: php

I'm creating a dynamic website with php & mysql. I've 2 folders, one is user and other is admin. In user folder i put user_logout.php page and in admin folder i put admin_logout.php. So that the issue is when i sign out from user panel it's successfully sign out from user panel **BUT** in the same time it's also sign out from Admin panel if i sign in.

**User_logout.php page**

```
<?php
include("db.php");
include("include/session.php");

$tm=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$q=mysql_query("UPDATE plus_user_login SET status='OFF', tm_out='$tm' WHERE 
id='$_SESSION[id]'");
echo mysql_error();

$see = $_SESSION['uname'];
session_unset($see);
session_destroy();
echo "<h1><center>You have been successfully Log Out</h1></center><br/>"; 
?>
```

**Admin_logout.php page**

```
<?php
include("include/session.php");
include("db.php");

$q=mysql_query("update plus_login set status='OFF' where id='$_SESSION[id]'");
session_unset($_SESSION['uname_ad']);
session_destroy();
echo "<br/>";
echo "<h1>You have been successfully Log Out</h1><br/>";

?>
```

Any help about this issue?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Session_destroy()
```

removing that code should solve your problem.

Although also make sure that you are not mixing up the session indexes while logging in.

EDIT:

What is $_SESSION['id'] doing in the code? I don't see how it is related to $_SESSION['uname'] and $_SESSION['uname_ad']?

If you are retrieving the status from database, try changing $_SESSION['id'] with $_SESSION['uname'] and $_SESSION['uname_ad'] in corresponding update query.

Also tell, how you check the login status. Against the database or only on basis of session data?

Comment: That was my original thought as well.  The problem is that the session_unset() command clears ALL entries in $_SESSION[]. In this case, that removes both the 'uname' and 'uname_ad' entries, effectively logging the user out of both sessions.

Comment: well @itachi, i use for login--- $_SESSION['id']= session_id();
$_SESSION['uname']=$uname; /  $_SESSION['id']= session_id();
$_SESSION['uname_ad']=$uname; is it right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both the session_unset() command and the session_destroy() commands are clearing the variable that controls both of your control panels.

1. Remove the session_destroy() commands from both pieces of code.
2. In your admin logout, replace session_unset($_SESSION['uname_ad']); with:

   $_SESSION['uname_ad'] = '';
3. In your user logout, replace session_unset($_SESSION[$see]); with:

   $_SESSION['uname'] = '';

Give that a try.